# MPMediaPlayer becomes small when i rotate it in ios 8

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, mpmovieplayercontroller, cgaffinetransform

I have application which plays video. 
It was great and good working in ios7 but now in iOs8 it is broken

```
self.player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:self.videoFileToDisplay];
[self.player play];

[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[self.player.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
UIView *playerView = self.player.view;

[self.view addSubview:playerView];
playerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[playerView]|"
                                                                  options:0
                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                    views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(playerView)]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[playerView]|"
                                                                  options:0
                                                                  metrics:nil
```

Also depending on horizontal or vertical video it is i need to rotate it

```
- (void)adoptVideoToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation withDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{

    CGFloat horizontalVideoAngle = 0;
    CGFloat verticalVideoAngle = 0;

    switch (toInterfaceOrientation) {
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            horizontalVideoAngle = 0;
            verticalVideoAngle = M_PI_2;
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            horizontalVideoAngle = 0;
            verticalVideoAngle = -M_PI_2;
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            verticalVideoAngle = 0;
            horizontalVideoAngle = M_PI_2;
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
            verticalVideoAngle = 0;
            horizontalVideoAngle = -M_PI_2;
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }

    CGFloat angle = [self isHorizontalVideo] ? horizontalVideoAngle : verticalVideoAngle;
    self.player.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( angle );
}
```

It is good at all orientations except portrait. Even UpsideDown is good
Here are screenshots

[image: portrait]
[image: LandscapeRight]
[image: UpsideDown]
[image: LandscapeLeft]

What is wrong with portrait orientation in ios8 ?

PS red view is background of mediaPlayer superview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Apple changed rotation in ios8 now it rotates content only and doesn't affect view frame. So i ended up adding additional scale transform